# Plotting multiple columns with a for loop in gnuplot, key doesn't work

Tags: for-loop, gnuplot

I have file with many columns that I'd like to plot as follows:

```
plot for [i=1:30] 'test' using 1:i w lp
```

This gives the plot I want, but when I do `set key`, then the key I see has all lines labeled as `1:i`:

[image]

How can I make this output more meaningful, by actually displayin the value of `i`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't set an explicit title, gnuplot selects an automatic title based on the *plain* plot command call. If you want a meaningful title, you must give it explicitly, like

```
plot for [i=1:30] 'test' using 1:i w lp title sprintf("column %d", i)
```